# Pushing message into JMS queue from Junit

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jndi

I am trying to push messages to a JMS Queue from a Junit testcase, but I keep getting the error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ConnectionFactory] not bound
```

Here is the testcase code:

```
public void testPushMessagesIntoQueue() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = (JmsTemplate) getBean("batchMessageTemplate"); //ERROR HERE
    assertNotNull(jmsTemplate);
    try {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("batchQueue", messageList);
    } catch(Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/service-context.xml");
}

public Object getBean(String beanName) {
    return getContext().getBean(beanName);
}
```

Here is my connection factory bean in service-context.xml file :

```
<bean name="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">  
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>  
    <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory" /> 
</bean>
```

And my jndiTemplate bean :

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="com.xxx.batch.common.util.CustomJndiTemplate">  
</bean>
```

In class customJndiTemplate, I set the properties as

```
       public CustomJndiTemplate() throws JobException {
          Properties environment = new Properties();
       environment.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
       environment.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");
       environment.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
       setEnvironment(environment);
       }
```

My batchMessageTemplate bean:

```
  <bean name="batchMessageTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="batchDestination" />  
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="1" />  
</bean>
```

In my Jbossmq-destinations-service.xml in my Jboss4, i have defined the queue :

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue"
 name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=batchQueue">
<depends optional-attribute-name="DestinationManager">jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager</depends>
```

When i run the testcase after starting jboss 4, I get the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in file [service-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ConnectionFactory] not bound;
```

This problem happens only when i run my Junit testcase.  have defined a servlet which runs within Jboss to add messages to the queue and it works fine

I'm new to JMS, so any help will be appreciated.